# Called From Wrong Thread Exception Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to create an app that when you touch the screen, a snowflake appears at the top of the screen and slowly falls. I am adding each snowflake to an arraylist so that I can make each snowflake fall. Here is my code:

```
Runnable runable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            letTheSnowFall();
        }
    }
};

public void letTheSnowFall(){
    for(int i = 0; i < snowArray.size(); i++){
        snowArray.get(i).setY(snowArray.get(i).getY() + 0.01f);
    }
}
```

and the I start the thread in the onCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    setContentView(layout);
    layout.setOnClickListener(listener);

    Thread myThread = new Thread(runable);
    myThread.start();
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize `snowArray`? Are you sure it is accessible from within `myThread`

Comment: You're calling your drawing (?) code on a thread, that isn't the UI thread and is probably trying to add the snowflakes to the window right? Try posting your `letTheSnowFall()` to the `Activity's` `Handler` instead or use the `runOnUiThread` method.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot update your UI from a background thread.

Second, an infinite background thread with no delays is exceedingly bad code.

Third, please do not call `setContentView()` twice in `onCreate()`. You do not need the second one (`setContentView(layout)`).

The lightest-weight way to accomplish this is to use `postDelayed()`, available on any `View` (such as `layout`), to arrange to get control in the future after a delay. You can cancel the `postDelayed()` work by calling `removeCallbacks()`, passing in the same `Runnable` as you used with `postDelayed()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.post;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity implements Runnable {
  private static final int PERIOD=5000;
  private View root=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    run();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    root.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(PostDelayedDemo.this, "Who-hoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
    root.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
  }
}
```

(code from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/PostDelayed))

In your case, `run()` would update your snowflakes instead of showing a `Toast`.

Comment: So what would root be in my case, would it just be the same?

Comment: @Cj1m: It could be just the same, or any other `View`, such as your `layout`.

Answer (score 1):

To update the view, you need to update it from the main thread. Clearly, you are doing it wrong. You can throw the information to the main thread and update it. Perhaps, you could try updating the view using Android built threads (AsyncTasks), compute the results on doInBackGround(), and publish the results on onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the snowflakes are views. So the snowArray has the type `ArrayList<SubtypeOfView>`. If so then the exception is throw because you call `View.setY()` method from a thread other than the main thred. Almost all of the methods related to the Android GUI framework have to be called from the main thread(the thread that executes callbacks such as `Activity.onCreate()`).

Comment: they are actually ImageViews but yes

Comment: In any case your approach isn't the best one for solving this problem. If you want to use only the Android library, then I would suggest implementing a custom view (a subclass of View) which will contain the rendering code. Otherwise you should use a more advanced graphics library. The Android library is too limited. One example of such a library is LibGDX, which is actually a game engine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `snowArray` contains a bunch of instances of [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (or one of its many subclasses)? In that case, you're trying to modify a GUI component from a non-GUI thread, which is not allowed and thus throws a `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

The "easy" solution would be to call [`Activity.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) wherever you need to modify the UI. This is useful if you've done some processing on a separate thread and are now ready to show the results on the GUI.

However, you want to do a lot of GUI updates. It's even worse, since you're doing updates in an infinite loop: `while(true) { letTheSnowFall(); }`. This thing is *truly* infinite: it will never stop and your snow will just keep falling forever, with the Y-coordinate rapidly incrementing and eventually overflowing. You won't see that happen though since as soon as the GUI has updated, you're immediately updating it again: there is *no delay*.

What you're trying to do is much simpler though: you just want to let the snow fall. You want to *animate* your snow flake views starting from their current position and ending some distance downward. Android has [a whole package for animations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html) along with some [very good guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html).

Comment: I plan on removing the snow when it goes off screen and adding a slight delay to make it 'less infinite'.

Comment: Still, you should look into animations. It'll make your life easier as you can rely on the framework to manage the timing and tweening. You can also use more advanced features, like accelerators or animation sets. Besides, most animations in Android can be done by the GPU, resulting in a much smoother experience.

Comment: Would it result in me having to rewrite lots of the application?